# Converting to lower-case: every letter gets tokenized

Tags: python, lowercase

I have a text document that I want to convert to lower case, but when I do it in the following way every letter of my document gets tokenized. Why does it happen?

```
with open('assign_1.txt') as g:
    assign_1 = g.read()
assign_new = [word.lower() for word in assign_1]
```

What I get:

```
assign_new
['b',
'a',
'n',
'g',
'l',
'a',
'd',
'e',
's',
'h',]
```

Comment: Anyway, the problem is probably that `g.read()` produces a string, which is an iterable of characters.

Comment: `for word in some_string` doesn't loop over words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterated through the entire input, one character at a time, dropped each to lower-case, and *specified* the result as a list.  It's simpler than that:

```
assign_lower = g.read().lower()
```

Using the variable "word" doesn't make you iterate over words -- `assign_1` still a sequence of characters.

If you want to break this into words, use the `split` method ... which is independent of the lower-case operation.